# Is ros-perception/open_karto different from nav2d_karto/OpenKarto?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The README in https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto says it's a catkinized version of SRI International's OpenKarto library.

In https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/tree/master/nav2d_karto/OpenKarto, Sebastian Kasperski has included a copy of the OpenKarto library (non-catkinized).

The question is, why does the source code look so different? Compare [open_karto/src](https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto/tree/indigo-devel/src) and [open_karto/include/open_karto](https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto/tree/indigo-devel/include/open_karto) with [nav2d_karto/OpenKarto/source](https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d/tree/master/nav2d_karto/OpenKarto/source). Was the library refactored as part of the catkinization?

Most importantly, are the two more or less equivalent?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225856/is-ros-perception/open_karto-different-from-nav2d_karto/openkarto-?/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the version used in nav2d_karto was called "OpenKarto 2.0" on the SRI-Homepage, so maybe the version in open_karto is the original one.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-05**:
I tried to confirm, but the [code.ros.org link](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/karto) mentioned on [SRI International's announcement](https://www.sri.com/newsroom/press-releases/sri-international-announces-release-karto-open-libraries-20) is ofc not working any more.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-05**:
I'll see if I can get one of the authors or maintainers of the open_karto package to comment.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-16**:
I noticed this in the Authors file of open_karto: `Karto Open Source Library 1.0`, However, there's also a `new open-source Karto` commit message (https://github.com/ros-perception/open_karto/commit/def830d7c019e7b75bb1face379cbaceb070e5f7) that coincides with the date of the 2.0 SRI announcement.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-02-16**:
To top that of, the copyright note in nav2d's version of Open Karto reads `Copyright (C) 2006-2011, SRI International (R)`. The "2011" confused me even more. It's as if there was another release after the May 2010 release of Open Karto 2.0